# filter dynamodb from list in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Spring boot application using an AWS DynamoDb table which contains a list of items as such:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = MemberDbo.TABLENAME)
public class MemberDbo {

    public static final String TABLENAME = "Member";

    @NonNull
    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    protected String id;

    // some more parameters

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private List<String> membergroupIds;

}
```

I would like to find all members belonging to one specific groupId. In best case I would like to use CrudRepository like this:

```
@EnableScan
public interface MemberRepository extends CrudRepository<MemberDbo, String> {

    List<MemberDbo> findByMembergroupIdsContaining(String membergroupIds); // actually I want to filter by ONE groupId

}
```

Unfortunately the query above is not working (`java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List`)

- Any suggestions how to build a correct query with CrudRepository?
- Any suggestions how to create a query with Amazon SDK or some other Springboot-compliant methods?
- Alternatively can I create a dynamoDb index somehow and filter by that index?
- Or do I need to create and maintain a new table programmatically containing the mapping between membergroupIds and members (which results in a lot of overhead in code and costs)?

A solution for CrudRepository is preferred since I may use Paging in future versions and CrudRepository easily supports paging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly this looks very easy. You using [DynamoDBMapper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html) for model persistence.

You have a member object, which contains a list of membergroupids, and all you want to do is retrieve this from the database. If so, using DynamoDBMapper you would do something like this:

```
AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);
MemberDbo member = mapper.load(MemberDbo.class, hashKey, rangeKey);
member.getMembergroupIds();
```

Where you need to replace hashKey and rangeKey. You can omit rangeKey if you don't have one.

DynamoDBMapper also supports [paging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/PaginatedQueryList.html) out of the box.

DynamoDBMapper is an excellent model persistence tool, it has strong features, its simple to use and because its written by AWS, it has seamless integration with DynamoDB. Its creators have also clearly been influenced by spring. In short, I would use DynamoDBMapper for model persistence and Spring Boot for model-controller stuff.